# I want to print some tag just after bootstrap input fields tag at the same line

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

[I want something just like this. But if it is showing below the input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCgqD.png). My code below displays the input fields, but I want it all on the same line. How can we do that?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="price">Price</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Price">
  <a class="btn">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You only have one `input` in the HTML example. Assuming you actually have multiple instances, then remove the block level `div` element wrapper, or set it to `display: inline-block;` in CSS, or use a `span` or some other inline element. The same goes for `label`, as that too is block level

Comment: X is not display at same line it display below the input fields however i use span also

Comment: Please show us what you tried, along with all relevant CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the children in `.form-group` to appear inline, the easiest way I would do it is with `display: flex`. [Here's a more in-depth guide on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```
.form-group {
   display: flex;
}
```